# C# WebApi wait for WebHook response

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, webhooks

I have a web service that receives a post from a client, and eventually sends a request to a different web service hosted by another company. That company uses a Callback/Webhook model where you send in a request, they immediately reply with a 204, and then they send the finished result via http post to a url I have configured (its a long running process and sometimes can take a while).

I would like to wait for a set amount of time to see if a response is returned timely from other company (like a 20 second timeout for example) and then return the results of the response from the other company. If they don't response within the timeout period, I will just return a generic result to my client with additional information about where they can get the rest of their data later.

What I am trying to figure out is how I can have one API controller wait for a request into another API controller and then get the data from that controller. I am thinking some kind of event system would be appropriate:

1. customer sends request to api endpoint on controller A
2. Controller A registers a handler to an event raised by controller B
3. 3rd Party sends Http Request to controller B
4. controller B publishes event that controller A is listening for along with data from 3rd party post
5. controller A (if timeout is not reached) returns response to client

There is quite a bit of utility code needed for this to work though. Is there a better way of handling a request/response model with a webhooks api?

Comment: Microsoft has ASP.NET WebHooks framework.

Comment: ^ Yeah and the documentation is horrid.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with so far.

```
            var _response = null;


        //send http request to platform, get back 204
        ...
        var sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        //subsribe to messages being published
        MessagePublisher.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;

        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (_response != null)
                    return _response; //we got a response

                if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > _messageTimeout)
                {
                    return null; //todo handle not receiving a response from the webhooks
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            //unregister event
            MessagePublisher.MessageReceived -= OnMessageReceived;
        }
    }

    private void OnMessageReceived(object sender, Message message)
    {
        //TODO convert the message to a filled in webservice response
        _response = new WebServiceResponse();
    }
}

// publishes the message when the other controller receives it
public static MessagePublisher
{
    public static event EventHandler<Message> MessageReceived;

    public static void OnMessageReceived(Message result)
    {
        EventHandler<Message> handler = MessageReceived;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(null, result);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: You probably should switch to `TPL`, waiting for two tasks: task from completion source, which will provide you the response, and cancellation task for the amount of time you're waiting. Such infinite loop is quite bad solution.